# How Can i create this transition

Tags: html, css, transition, slidedown

I have been tasked with creating a new dropdown menu for our company website.  Our designer has found one from another site that has a very specific dropdown transition that we want to use.  If you visit www.snowbird.com on your mobile phone, and click on the plus sign in the upper left hand side of the screen, you will get a slideDown effect that shows the full navigation.  It is not just a slide down, but it also rols a little bit, like a cube effect.  I have not been able to find out what this transition is.  I didnt see it in jqueryui.com and another dozen or so sites on css3 animations etc...
Does anybody know what kind of transition this is and do i have to custom make it or if there is a name for it i can find.
Thanks

Comment: why did people give me a mark down for asking a question?  makes me feel like i can ask anything here.

Comment: You're [not supposed](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to ask *anything* here. Appropriate questions usually include code/markup and context reproducing a particular issue. This question doesn't - instead it asks people to visit a site and then identify a particular transition effect. http://ux.stackexchange.com *may* be more appropriate for this question.

Comment: That being said, it's a shame that people down-vote without leaving a comment or appropriate close-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this animation is same to the push with a little delay. same a this http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/panel/ but in top.